# How to find prime numbers between two user input numbers without using a seperate function in java

Tags: java

I have been attempting to find the bug to the program for about 30 minutes and it is annoying me.  If you input the first number as 2 and the second number as 9, the output is : 3 4 5 6 7 8.  It just displays the numbers in between rather than the prime numbers in between.  Here is the code: (Please help)

```
public class PrimeNumber {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1, num2, counter;
    boolean prime = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter an integer greater than the previous: ");
    num2 = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    for (int k = num1; k <= num2; k++){
       prime = true;

       for (int j = num2; j <= k; j++){
           if (k % j == 0){
               prime = false;  
           }
       }
       if (prime == true){
           System.out.println(k);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [@Scott Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter) and the others:

> There are logic errors in your for-loop for checking the primality of a given number.

I would recommend you to separate the primality test into a different function, this really helps you in debugging. I have implemented a native primality test below for your reference:

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ....

        for (int k = num1; k <= num2; k++) {
            if (isPrime(k)) {
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int k) {
        if (k < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
                if (k % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you insist to have everything inside the main method (*which is definitely not a good practice!*), the modification should be very straight forward:

```
public class PrimeNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ....

        for (int k = num1; k <= num2; k++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;

            if (k < 2) {
                isPrime = false;
            } else {
                for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
                    if (k % i == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah see, I would have separated it into a new function but my teacher does not want it like that.

Comment: @versucci This is not a good practice in general, but if you insist, it can be modified directly from the code I posted. I have updated my solution for your reference

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to look at the function you wrote previously and fix my program based off of that. I think we are learning how to write these methods in the next chapter. @chiwangc

Comment: Surely you only need to test until `sqrt` of `k` - anything past that can't have an integer divisor that hasn't been tested yet: `for (int i = 2; i * i <= k; i++)`

Comment: @sprinter Indeed, it does improve the performance considerably. I just want to keep it simple here. In practice, I would go for something much more efficient like the Miller–Rabin test

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop never executes the `if` inside unless `j == k == num2`.

Comment: How would I be able to fix this issue then?